# kubernetes pods is forbidden: User "user1" cannot list pods in the namespace "stage"

Tags: kubernetes, alibaba-cloud

while testing the role based access in the Alibaba container service it's throwing with me an error **"pods is forbidden: User "user1" cannot list pods in the namespace "stage""** this is RBAC issue, which i'm not able to figure it where i'm heading it wrong

**The RoleBinding Definition**

```
root@kube-master:# kubectl describe rolebinding stage-role-binding  -n stage
Name:         stage-role-binding
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  Role
  Name:  staging
Subjects:
  Kind  Name   Namespace
  ----  ----   ---------
  User  user2
```

**The Role Definition**

```
root@kube-master:# kubectl describe role -n stage
Name:         staging
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources               Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------               -----------------  --------------  -----
  deployments             []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
  pods                    []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
  replicasets             []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
  deployments.apps        []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
  pods.apps               []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
  replicasets.apps        []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
  deployments.extensions  []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
  pods.extensions         []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
  replicasets.extensions  []                 []              [get list watch create update patch delete]
```

**One pod is running well in the stage namespace**

```
root@kube-master:# kubectl get pods -n stage 
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
busybox   1/1       Running   0          10m
```

**Defining context**

```
root@kube-master:# kubectl config set-context stage --cluster=kubernetes --namespace=stage --user=user2
Context "stage" modified.
```

**Testing RBAC**

```
root@kube-master:/home/ansible# kubectl --context=stage get pods
No resources found.
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "user1" cannot list pods in the namespace "stage"
```

Not sure from where **user1**

> is coming and throwing the RBAC Error

There is only **context** is set for **user2**

```
root@kube-master:# kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                          CLUSTER      AUTHINFO           NAMESPACE
*         kubernetes-admin@kubernetes   kubernetes   kubernetes-admin   
          stage                         kubernetes   user2              stage
```

**This is how i created the user**

```
openssl genrsa -out user2.key 2048
openssl req -new -key user2.key -out user2.csr -subj "/CN=user1/O=8gwifi.org"
openssl x509 -req -in user2.csr -CA /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -CAkey /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out user2.crt -days 500

kubectl config set-credentials user2 --client-certificate=user2.crt --client-key=user2.key
kubectl config set-context stage --cluster=kubernetes --namespace=stage --user=user2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RoleBinding is for user **user2**, not for **user1**. That's why you are getting RBAC error.

Setting context for user **user2** does not mean that kubernetes will identify this user as **user2**. It depends on the credential you use. If the used credential is of user **user-x**, then kubernetes will treat it as **user-x**. The **context user** is for kubectl to find user credential info. To understand kubernetes authentication see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/).

The credential you used there resolved to user **user1**. So you should update your RoleBinding to **user1**.

**After updated question**

For certificate authetication, **CN** will be the username (ref: [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#x509-client-certs)).
In your certificate `"/CN=user1/O=8gwifi.org"`, so username will be **user1** not **user2**.

Comment: @anish see my answer. still reason is same